# How to represent this data model in a Scalable Way

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

I want all the below information for Each ServerName Corresponding to particular date
Like For Todays Date we have to get the below information for each Server(Server Name) suppose if we have 3 servers then we need the below information for todays date for all the 3 servers. In the same way for tomorrow for all the 3Servers I need all this below information corresponding to that particular date. How can I represent this model.

These are the column names

```
updown 
docs  
indexsize  
cachehits  
lastcommit   
lastoptimize   
lastreplicationtime   
presentqueries   
slowqueries   
totalqueries
```

So I think it is One to Many relationship model. With one as date and Many means server name.  Sample table that I have designed..!!

[image]

Sample Solution based on Larsenal Update

[image]

Comment: Are you storing anything else in the table with the dates?

Comment: @Larsenal, in which table u r asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you show here, I see no compelling reason to have a separate table with the dates.

Given the information you provided, I'd just add the date column to your primary table.  In your consumer code, you can easily create something along the lines of:

```
val r = ServerStats.forDate('2011-10-17');
```

That generates SQL similar to

```
SELECT * FROM ServerStats WHERE Date = '2011-10-17'
```

Comment: so you want me to add date field into Table B by removing REID Foreign Key column and then query directly from table B using date and server name.

Comment: Yes.  Is there anything else in "Table A" that warrants a separate table?

Comment: nothing is there in Table A.. I updated the question with the solution as per your suggestions. This is the way you are talking about...? And one more thing it is not necessary that we will be having only three server.. It can be more also like 10-20.. So this design is scalable enough??

Comment: This will scale just fine.  Once things get really big, you can twiddle your database indexes to optimize things further.

Comment: Replacing real data (the date) with an id number has nothing to do with normalization. So *over-normalization* is the wrong term here. "Don't do it" is the right solution, though.